# Use google doc API in asp.net C# web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am developing a web application in C#.net. I need to edit a file placed on the server in browser it self(Without downloading it on local machine) and when I save that file, the changes should be reflected in file. For this I want to use google API but I don't know how can I use this.
I want to do like below.

1. When I click on file name, it should open in browser.
2. When clicked on edit, it open in edit mode in browser using google doc.
3. When I save that file, the changes should be reflected in my file which is placed on company server.

How can I do all this thing with google doc API?

Answer (score 1):

Install Google Drive on your server.
Edit the file in Google docs, let Google Drive sync it to the local hard drive.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your answer in detail?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible for HTTP protocol, because the basics system doesn;t support it. You can open the file but the file will be downloaded to your local machine in then it will open, you have to specify the MIME type in IIS.

You can use two ways to do a similar job done.

1 By Using FTP

2 Customized solution : Make a page put a text field and load the file (.cs) in it and with submit save it to the file back.

Comment: How google docs doing the things? I want to do the same thing as it is done in google docs

Comment: Google doc download the file data to local machine open it and when you press save it post back the file to the server, for not losing data it automatically post back the data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a google doc in Webpages. But the file would be accessed and saved on Google's servers and not your company server:
Wordpress allows you to do it. Potentially you can see if it possible to do it in a similar way:
http://en.support.wordpress.com/google-docs/

I am not sure if Google has an option of accessing docs from servers outside google's domain.

Comment: Its ok if the file is uploaded and edited on google's server but when I save that file, the edited file should replace the older file on my server